# Add "Next" button to search form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have written a basic search form which searches the text of a TextBox and highlights the 1st instance of the search term if found, so far I have this bit of code but would like to somehow implement a "next" button to the form which when clicked will go to the next instance, click again and go to next etc. Can anyone help me?

```
Dim Search As String
        Dim Find As String
        Search = TextBox1.Text
        Find = InStr(Form1.TextBox1.Text, Search)
        If Find Then
            Form1.TextBox1.Focus()
            Form1.TextBox1.SelectionStart = Find - 1
            Form1.TextBox1.SelectionLength = Len(Search)
        Else
            MsgBox("Can't find the text:" & Environment.NewLine & Search)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function has a parameter which lets you start searching from a particular index. In this case it would be the index of the word that's been found plus the length of the word itself.

```
Find = InStr(Find + Len(Search), Form1.TextBox1.Text, Search)
```

In this case, we're starting at position `Find + Len(Search)`. Untested, but I think that should do what you want.

Probably a premature optimization but you could store the length of the search term so it doesn't have to be calculated each time the `Next` button is pressed.